# Совместимость Java и Kotlin лямбд

Tags: java, kotlin

Если я пишу `Class::method` в kotlin классе, передавая в метод, определенный в java классе, это не работает(разные типы). Наоборот тоже не работает. Писать длиннущие лямбды, когда можно `Class::method` не хочется, есть ли способ как то совместить :: и разные языки в 1 проекте?

Comment: в одном проекте можно, в одном файле вряд ли

Comment: [Приведите пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)